# how to only get a file as an output in bash script

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to only get the file output in my script using the find function. But instead I get the path leading to the file:

Example:

```
file1= `ls -1| find ${in_directory_with_file} -name "filename" -type f| head -1`
```

Actual output => "in_directory_with_file/filename"

However I just want output => "filename"

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. If you already have the ```filename``` why bother ```find```ing it? Are you trying to check if the file exists in a specific directory? Could you please elaborate your question and show us more of the code and tell us what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: the file that I'm pulling contains data that is needed for another program running in the background. I don't need the path I just need the file. the script is written as such simplified: go into datafolder/in_directory_with_file/ *filename* I need the filename by itself to be used as a separate variable. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: That's still not making any sense for me. Please, check ["How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: If ```$in_directory_with_file``` has just one file in there and you want to find out what is its name you can simply do ```file1=$(basename ${in_directory_with_file}/*)```.

Comment: The extra space after `file1=` should be causing problem. I think you need to post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Use the `basename` command.

```sh
basename $file1
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, this will strip the leading part of the file found by the find program and give you just the file (base) name:

```
basename $(find ${in_directory_with_file} -name "filename" -type f| head -1)
```

I'm not sure why the ls -1 is needed in you question. I don't think find reads from stdin.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks! There are several files in the directory so I was trying to locate that specific file and create a variable for it. file1= basename $(find ${in_directory_with_file} -name "filename" -type f works. I removed the "head -1"